# How to Apply customize analytical model in OBIEE12c

Tags: oracle, obiee

I would like to integrate machine learning model developed by python with obiee 12c dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You should use In-Database Machine Learning then present it in the obiee.
Oracle Machine Learning for Python (OML4Py) is a Python API for performing statistical and machine learning analysis on data in your Oracle Autonomous Database.
With Embedded Python Execution, you can run user-defined Python functions in Python engines spawned by the Autonomous Database environment.
Automated Machine Learning (AutoML) enhances user productivity and machine learning results through automated algorithm and feature selection, as well as model selection and tuning.
For more information visit this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/machine-learning/oml4py/1/index.html).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).